# Scaling MySQL database and improve performance when number of queries increase

Tags: mysql, performance, django-rest-framework, load, scalability

We have a system which consists of a REST application built on Django. The database we are using is MYSQL. Both the servers are hosted in AWS.

- Currently hundreds of POST requests come to our application.
- We dump the request body into our database on each hit.
- The frequency of requests is huge (around 100 in a minute).

Our next task is to process the data which we receive. Currently we have scheduled a job which runs in every 1 minute.

This job has logic to extract data from tables which is not processed already and based on our logic it updates other tables in the database.
Simultaneously there are large number of queries which are executing.
During peak hours when there is too much inflow of data, the queries get locked and our system become overwhelmed. Sometimes we have to kill the queries to free the system.

What are the ways in which we can reduce the turnaround time of queries and also ensure that all queries are executed in less time ? How can we ensure that queries do not get locked ?

Comment: Additional information request.  Which AWS model? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Another way to do high speed ingestion.  It has a feedback loop to keep it from stumbling like you described:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

Comment: What the heck is going on where "huge" is a mere 100/minute?

Comment: @nitin          If you are still experiencing troubles with performance, please CONSIDER posting information requested on Apr 27, 2020 and you will receive some valuable suggestions. Welcome bsck to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have chosen correct database according to your needs and if mysql is what you need then there are some ways you can optimize it.

1. Chose right db engine - seems your system is write heavy so chose some engine  that works on row level locking like innodb.
2. Indexing - make proper indexes for optimizing read and update.
3. Use master-slave arch in and route all read to slave and write to master.
4. And still you are facing issue then go for sharding and distribute load on each shard, apart from sharding mysql does not provide any other solution for write heavy system.
5. If size of data is less then you can keep all shards on one instance and make use of CPU cores.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. We are already following 1 and  2. We will try out other options.

Comment: If your tables are already using the InnoDB engine and you are still getting locking issues on a regular basis, you are doing something quite badly sub-optimal in your algorithm. What you are effectively describing is a message queueing system, so you need to think about it from that perspective. For example, you need to rethink how your worker process fetches and processes the records without clashing with other worker threads.

Comment: You mean using master-slave configurations for the database system. Master for writing and slave for reading ? How message queuing is going to help resolve our issue?

Comment: @GordanBobic      As per my understanding the message queue system will decrease load on the service which is processing all the requests. So far we have not observed any major issue with our REST service. We are using Django REST framework.

Comment: We are using Django REST framework with Nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

100 requests/minute or 1.667 inserts/ second is not too busy.

Make sure you have an index on the flag used to lookup the unprocessed rows.

Make sure transactions are committed after each insert. It would be best to use auto commit.

It would help if more detailed information was given like the table structure but this is where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are working on a MySQL database which has many pros, but I might recommend trying SingleStore database too-- the problem which you are facing could be sorted out during the tuning process.

SingleStore database can scale-out architecture quickly and efficiently, responding to growing workloads leveraging commodity hardware without add-ons or specialized tuning expertise.